# Proving that a Linear Transformation of a Subspace is a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am having some trouble proving this:

[image]

My attempt for the first part is to construct a corresponding system **Ax = b** Then check to see if this system is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. However, it only seems to be closed under addition when **b = 0**

This probably means that I am approaching this problem the wrong way. Any tips on where to begin? Thanks.

Comment: something is a subspace if it's closed under addition and scaling. Use the definition.

Comment: To start you off, if you take $b_1, b_2 \in T(U)$, you have to show $b_1+b_2 \in T(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that this is a subspace, we need to show that it is non-empty and closed under scalar multiplication and addition. We know it is non-empty because $T(0_{m}) = 0_{n}$, so $0_{n} \in T(U)$.

Now, suppose $c \in R$ and $v_{1}, v_{2} \in T(U)$. We need to show that $cv_{1} + v_{2} \in T(U)$.

Note that since $v_{1}, v_{2} \in T(U)$, there exists some $w_{1}, w_{2} \in R^{m}$ such that $T(w_{1}) = v_{1}, T(w_{2}) = v_{2}$. Since $R^{m}$ is a vector space, $cw_{1} + w_{2} \in R^{m}$.

Now, by the properties of a linear transformation, we know that $T(cw_{1}+w_{2}) = cT(w_{1}) + T(w_{2}) = cv_{1} + v_{2}$.

I am done, I constructed a member of $R^{m}$ that maps to $cv_{1} + v_{2}$, and thus it must be that $cv_{1} + v_{2} \in T(U)$.